# Unable to change color of icon-bar in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I unhover the icon-bar(which appears in mobile or when zoomed in) after clicking it, the color changes back to default. It is not supposed to change color after unhover/mouseout.

Here is the link to my site: https://bgrnature.herokuapp.com/

html:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

I tried this but still didn't work:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle{
    background: #51a746;
    color: #fff !important;
    border-color: #51a746;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover{
    background-color: #51a746;
}
```

Comment: @HunterTurner Yeah icon-bars appear on mobile or when screen is zoomed in. Sorry my bad. I thought most people would know about icon-bars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with the .navbar-toggle's :hover but with :focus. To fix the issue, change this in your css to fix the issue:

Replace this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover{
    background-color: #51a746;
}
```

with this:

```
 .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
     background-color: #51a746;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right. It was the problem with focus